# hibernate generator won't insert with uniqueidentifier

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, uniqueidentifier, sql-server-2008-express

I'm trying to map an entity using Hibernate Annotations, so that when a record is created and saved (via cascade), an ID is automatically generated. With my current setup (or a few others I've tried) I get the following error:

```
    ...org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
could not insert: [com.gorkwobbler.shadowrun.karma.domain.AttributeScore]
    ...java.sql.SQLException: 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'KARMA_DEV.dbo.Character'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I can see the following insert statement being issued:

```
Hibernate: insert into character (version, alias, firstName, lastName) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Clearly this is wrong, there is no "id" parameter.

My table schema, for now, is simply:

```
Character(
 id uniqueidentifier, --primary key
 alias varchar(max),
 firstName varchar(max),
 lastName varchar(max),
 version int --for hibernate
)
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, Express edition.

My annotations are split between a mapped superclass, DomainEntity, and a concrete class, KarmaCharacter:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DomainEntity implements Serializable /* Needed for HOM retainUnsaved */ {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String id;
    private Integer version;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Generated(value=GenerationTime.INSERT)
    //@GeneratedValue(generator="hibernate-uuid.hex")
    //@GenericGenerator(name="hibernate-uuid.hex", strategy="org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator", parameters=@Parameter(name="separator", value="-"))
    @AccessType(value="field")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Version
    @AccessType(value="field")
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="character")
public class KarmaCharacter extends DomainEntity {
    private String alias;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    private SortedSet<AttributeScore> attributeScores;

    public KarmaCharacter() {
        //default constructor
    }

    @Column
    @AccessType(value="field")
    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    @Column
    @AccessType(value="field")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Column
    @AccessType(value="field")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

//...omitted some transient code and a collection property for brevity

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    } 

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

If someone could tell me the right way to generate uniqueidentifer-type ID's with hibernate in SQL Server, and get them to be saved properly, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can see the following insert statement being issued (...). Clearly this is wrong, there is no "id" parameter.

Indeed, when using the `uniqueidentifier` SQL Server type, Hibernate has to use `newid()`. But your current annotations are not telling it to do so. I think you need the [*`guid`*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) generator here:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Some additional remarks:

- The GUID column type is really meant to hold a GUID generated by Microsoft's algorithm, you can't use Hibernate's UUID algorithm.
- You don't need the `Generated` annotation on an `Id`, just remove it.
- I also wonder why you are "messing" wit `AccessType`, I would just remove them.
- I would actually not use a GUID (see [this article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)) but this is another story.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I hoped for, I didn't know how to make hibernate use newid().

Comment: I use the @AccessType because there is no setId() method. I did it this way because there's no reason for my application code to change the id.

Comment: @RMorrisey: I see (but I would make the setter protected then)